# A numerical scheme for finding radical matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, soft-question, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization

If the goal would be to solve the (matrix) equation:
$${\bf P}^2 = {\bf A}$$
Do you think a numerical scheme alternatingly minimizing for $\bf P_1, P_2$ would be stable:
$$\|{\bf P_1P_2-A}\|_2,\hspace{1cm} \|{\bf P_1-P_2}\|_2$$

I do not expect there to be any unique solution. On the contrary I am especially interested in the cases when there aren't, as the approach would be very convenient in providing ways of incorporating constraints on a solution ( if we can get it to work ).

Comment: I think the standard situation is when $A$ is diagonalizable; in this case you can read off its square root from the diagonalization. (Of course the diagonalization may be difficult to calculate.)

Comment: Yes then any matrix having diagonal elements under the same similarity solving the equation will suffice. Depending on the field of scalars that can still be some combinations, for example if we are working over $\mathbb C$ we will get 2 possibilities for most elements which will still give us $2^n$ combinations (if we are lucky).

Comment: But there also exist many other solutions. For example square root $\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right]$ of $I_2$ will not be findable by diagonalization.

Comment: Wait I was wrong of course it will be. But the diagonalization will not always be a natural or enlightening description of what one wants to perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use iterative methods. [Babylonian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix), can be an option.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this approach proves to have some merit. To take a elementary example, we take maybe the simplest case $\bf A=I$ or in other words an operation which is it's own inverse - an *involution*. We choose to conduct our experiments over $\mathbb C^{6}$ and starting with random matrices $\bf P_1$ and $\bf P_2$.

After 6 iterations, we calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $\bf P_1$ and we do get:

$${\bf D} = \left[\begin{array}{rrrrrr}-1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&0&1\end{array}\right] \pm {\bf I}\cdot10^{-4}$$
which is completely reasonable as the set of solutions to $x^2=1$ over our field of scalars is $x\in \{-1,1\}$

We can then keep going restarting on the solution found ($\bf A = P_1$) and iterating 12 times:

$${\bf D} = \left[\begin{array}{rrrrrr}1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&-i&0&0&0&0\\0&0&i&0&0&0\\0&0&0&-1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&0&0&-1\end{array}\right] \pm {\bf I}\cdot 10^{-4}$$

which is also reasonable since the roots to $x^4 = 1$ are $x \in \{-1,1,-i,i\}$ and if we look carefully we see that $x^2 = -1$ have exactly two roots stemming from the two $-1$ above : $\{i,-i\}$, the other four, $\{1,-1,-1,-1\}$ stem from the 1 eigenvalues.

---

If this works well there is in theory no stopping us from doing a kind of iterative refinement solving ${\bf P}^{2^k} = {\bf A}$ by first solving ${\bf P}^2 = {\bf A}$ and then setting ${\bf A = P}$ and iterating $k$ times.